# String matching algorithms for different languages

Tags: php, string, python-2.7, string-matching, levenshtein-distance

I am creating an application where two strings would be compared for accuracy. For strings in English, I am using Levenshtein function available in PHP. I want to know whether it can be used for strings in languages like french, german, dutch, spanish etc?
Or is there any other library available in python or php for string matching which would also work for different languages?

Thanks